# how to create new variable from loop index in python

Tags: python

i have the following sort of code

```
 ps=[1,2,3,4]
 for subj in ps:
    num=num+1 
    datapath='/home/subj%d' %(int(subj))
     if num==1: 
       d1= pd.read_csv(datapath,  'words.csv')

     if num==2: 
       d2= pd.read_csv(datapath,  'words.csv')

     if num==3: 
       d3= pd.read_csv(datapath,  'words.csv')

     if num==4: 
       d4= pd.read_csv(datapath,  'words.csv')
```

which I would like to simplify i.e. to assign the csv file to a new d[num] variable such as the following, which wont work

```
ps=[1,2,3,4]

for subj in ps:

    num=num+1 

    datapath='/home/subj%d' %(int(subj))

    d[num] = pd.read_csv(datapath,  'numbers.csv')
```

d[num] should be a different numeric dataset for every loop

any suggestions please? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list and append the data.

```
ps=[1,2,3,4]
d = []
for subj in ps:
    datapath = '/home/subj%d' % (subj)
    d.append(pd.read_csv(datapath, 'numbers.csv'))
```

You can access the data with `d[0]` to `d[3]`.

Using a list comprehension will lead to the following code:

```
ps = [1,2,3,4]
d = [pd.read_csv('/home/subj%d' %(subj), 'numbers.csv') for subj in ps]
```

Comment: However, how would I go about it if the data file were datasets loaded from h5py? the above code does not work in this case

Comment: I'm not familiar with h5py, but that's the standard solution to do this task. You might want to ask a new question with updated information and in that question please explain why you can't use a simple loop with an `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
paths = map('/home/subj{}'.format, ps)
datas = map(pd.read_csv, paths)
```

Now you have a list of DataFrames, but if you want separate variables, you can:

```
d1, d2, d3, d4 = datas
```

Comment: You will have to use `datas = list(map(pd.read_csv, paths))` if you're working with Python 3.x.

Comment: @Matthias: That's true, though the OP is almost certainly using Python 2, given their use of the ancient `%` formatter.